# MIPS - storing values into an array using a loop trouble

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am relatively new to MIPS and have been finding example problems to expand my skills. I am faced with this problem:

> Subtract elements of one arrary from another and replace  values in
>   the first array.
>
> Given arrays a and b, each 10 words long, for each value i  where 0
>   <= i < 10, let c = A[i] - B[i]. Then, if c < 0  set A[i] = 0.
>   Otherwise, set A[i] = c.
>
> Complete the code so that the data values are correctly loaded,
>   computed and stored. You must use a loop to iterate through the loads
>   and stores

Here is my coded attempt, however I notice my `$12` and `$13` are not loading in the first value of `a` and `b` respectively as I would like them to. Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

```
.data 0x10010000
.word 23     # a[0]
.word 6
.word 11
.word 7
.word 44
.word 32
.word 9
.word 16
.word 29
.word 13

.data 0x10010040
.word 6  # b[0]
.word 22
.word 9
.word 1
.word 3
.word 15
.word 10
.word 4
.word 30
.word 8


.text
.globl main



main:

lui $16, 0x1001  # $16 contains the address of a[0]

add $17, $16, 0
ori $17, $17, 0x0040     # $17 contains the address of b[0]
li $9, 0                #initiate iterator value
loop: 
lw $12, 0($16)      #load register with value of a
nop
lw $13, 0($17)      #load register with value of b
nop

li $8, 0                #set c to 0
sub $8, $12, $13        # c = A(i) - B(i)
blt $8, 0, negative     # if c is negative branch
nop
li $12, 0
add $12, $12, $8        #else A(i) = c
addi $9, $9, 1          #add 1 to iteration value
sw $12, 0($16)          #store value back into a
nop
bne $9, 10, update      #check that we have not the last array
nop
b exit                  #if so finish program
nop
negative:
li $12, 0
sw $12, 0($16)          #store value back into a
addi $9, $9, 1          #add 1 to iteration value
beq $9, 10, exit
nop
b loop
nop
update:
add $16, $16, 4         #move to the next value in a
add $17, $17, 4         #move to next value in b
b loop
nop
exit:
b exit
nop
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating your pointers (`$16` and `$17`) when the result of the subtraction is negative.
You should remove the lines

```
  nop
  b loop
  nop
```

located after the `beq $9, 10, exit` after the `negative` label.

Something else I noticed in your code is that you put a `nop` after every `lw` and `sw`, which is not needed.

Comment: Thanks I totally missed that. However I still have the issue that when executing this line of code:  lw $12, 0($16) and  lw $13, 0($17) I expect to see values of 23 and 6 get stored in these registers for the first iteration, instead I get the value 0 for both, hence my program never actually enters 'negative:' why is it not loading in the first byte of my array? Thanks again! @gusbro

Comment: I tried your code in MARS 4.2 and it works fine (after removing the lines mentioned in this answer). Try running your code step by step and you should see that register `$12` gets value `0x17` and register `$13` gets value `0x6`. Maybe you are not running the code you posted...